# what ways are there for mobile web design?

Tags: mobile, web

I want to know how to design a website. The website is shown normal on the web and mobile, but I need to know which one is better?

1. Design two different templates (one template for mobile and the other one for a normal monitor).
2. Check online through the user's device to see if its using a mobile device so I can change the stylesheet.

Is this correct? If there are any ideas, please tell me.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I would go for 1. Normally you don't want to show as much content on your mobile website as your "normal" desktop website. But include a link to your normal website from your mobile website.

Answer (score 0):

I would go for one, as axelios suggested, I would include a link.

I, as a user, find extremely annoying websites that refuse to display the full site because they "recognised my browser as a mobile browser". Several newssites do that, which has eventually diminished the number of news I read, and some shops did so, which means I don't visit their sites anymore... so I strongly discourage the second solution.